# How to change or customize Windows 7 control (minimize, restore, and close) buttons

Tags: windows-7, windows, themes

I use Windows 7 Home Basic, and have noticed that the window control buttons (minimize, restore, and close buttons) change when I switch from Windows 7 **Aero** theme to Windows 7 **Basic** theme.

[image: buttons]

Thus I believe that it is possible to customize these buttons.

**How can I make my control buttons look like "Windows 8" control buttons.** like in the image below;

[image: Windows 8 buttons]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your theme by installing custom third-party visual styles. Official Windows theme packs only include desktop background pictures, window colors, and sounds. Most custom themes are visual styles which can change the complete windows look - including the min/max/close buttons. In other words, with the right visual style your Windows 7 can **look** like Windows 8.

First, you'd have to find a visual style that appeals to you by browsing places like [deviantART](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/windows7/visualstyle/), [Windows 7 Themes](http://windows7themes.net/), or something similar. Just search these sites with your keywords and try to find something you like. If you can't find a suitable visual style, you can always create your own - depending on what you want to change it may take you anywhere from a couple of minutes to months to achieve.

Installing unsigned themes isn't as easy as installing an official theme pack and it's always a good idea to create a backup first but there are a lot of guides out there, like [this one](http://windows7themes.net/how-to-install-windows-7-themes.html) on Windows 7 Themes.

Comment: Yeah, UX theme patcher + custom theme, or something like WindowBlinds with a Win8 skin.